# search with in_array for (null, false)

Tags: php, arrays, array-intersect

I am trying to validate if `filter_var_array` filtered some input.
According to PHP doc `filter_var_array` return `false` if filter fails or `null` if variable is not set.

I have created a little test to check how to search for (null ,false)
inside arrays and I got some weird results

```
$tmp = $tmp = array(null, 1, 'test', 100, false);
$arr = array(null, false);

$x = in_array(array_map('strtolower',$arr), array_map('strtolower', $tmp), true);
var_dump($x);

$x = in_array(array_map('strtolower', $tmp), array_map('strtolower',$arr), true);
var_dump($x);
```

**output**:

```
boolean false

boolean false
```

am I doing something wrong?

**EDIT**:
The answer is given in a comment by [@sg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32646135/search-with-in-array-for-null-false/32646497?noredirect=1#comment53140764_32646497).

The way to do this is by using `array_intersect`.

```
$tmp = array(null, 1, 0, FALSE, 'test', NULL, 100, false);
$arr = array(null, false);

$x = array_intersect($tmp, $arr);
var_dump($x);
```

**output**:

```
array (size=4)
  0 => null
  3 => boolean false
  5 => null
  7 => boolean false
```

**important notes**:
1. If $needle is array. `in_array` search for a full-array match
2. `array_intersect` is type strict

Comment: What is your expected output

Comment: ...and in this special case: why? ;-)

Comment: @Uchiha TRUE if needle is found in the array, FALSE otherwise

Comment: @VolkerK trying to validate if filter_var_array filtered some input. can you suggest a better way?

Comment: no no, I meant why you exepct a different result. E.g. what is `array_map(strtolower, [null,false])` supposed to do? And what do you think the result does as $needle in in_array($needle, $haystack) ?

Comment: @VolkerK, sorry i don't get your point. can you please clarify?

Answer (score 0):

> am I doing something wrong?

Yes:

1. You're treating null and false as strings by passing them to strtolower. That's not a good idea.
2. in_array doesn't work like that. At the moment your asking it to find an array containing null and false inside the first array.  It doesn't iterate through each of the values in the needle searching each one individually.  Try this to see:

   `$tmp = array(array(null, false), 1, 'test', 100, false);`

   `$arr = array(null, false);`

   `$x = in_array($arr, $tmp, true);`

   `var_dump($x);`

   `$x = in_array($tmp, $arr, true);`

   `var_dump($x);`
3. Your statement about in_array's return values is incorrect. in_array "Returns TRUE if needle is found in the array, FALSE otherwise."

Comment: 1. you are right. but it doesn't work even without the strtolower.  2.i am not searching for a full array of (null, false), i am looking for one of the needle elements.  3.look at the question and the comments. i stated exactly the return value each function returns

Comment: Re: 2. Your example does search for a full array.  You can do that using array_intersect.  This might achieve what you want.

Comment: Thanks @sg array_intersect does the job correctly. it's important to state that array_intersect is type strict